# Change data-content in a bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm really new to coding, I've searched a bit to try to find an answer and I feel like there's a very simple way to do this, but the answers I find I can't understand.

I have this example which shows the popover.

```
<span data-toggle="popover" title="Test" data-content="Test"
id="test">popover</span>
```

I want to change the content of data-content in my JavaScript file

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
document.getElementById('test').setAtribute('data-content','hello');
```

Comment: it's not because you misspelled `setAttribute` is it?

Comment: Embarrassingly enough, that appears to be it... thanks! Lol.

Comment: cool, I added an answer to that effect with a bit of explanation. Feel free to select it as the answer if it answers your questions. And, welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

As you are using jquery, try setting the value for content as shown below,

```js
$('#test').data('content', 'hello');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-toggle="popover" title="Test" data-content="Test"
id="test">popover</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can be a dangerous tool... it can and will silently do nothing if what you write is not valid Javascript.

So this line: 
`document.getElementById('test').setAtribute('data-content','hello');`

has a misspelling in 'SetAt**t**ribute', which tries to call a function that doesn't actually exist (since it's misspelled), and so it does nothing at all.

First step when debugging: re-read your code carefully!